# Best way to understand big and complex SQL queries with many subqueries

Tags: sql, db2, subquery

I just started in a new project, in a new company.

I was given a big and complex SQL, with about 1000 lines and MANY subqueries, joins, sums, group by, etc.

This SQL is used for report generation (it has no inserts nor updates).

The SQL has some flaws, and my first job in the company is to identify and correct these flaws so that the report shows the correct values (I know the correct values by accessing a legacy system written in Cobol...)

How can I make it easier for me to understand the query, so I can identify the flaws?

As an experienced Java programmer, I know how to refactor a complex bad written monolitic Java code into an easier to understand code with small pieces of code. But I have no clue on how to do that with SQL.

The SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT columns
FROM
    (SELECT columns
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT columns
              FROM table000 alias000
              INNER JOIN                                          
                      table000 alias000             
               ON column000 = table000.column000

              LEFT JOIN
                 (SELECT columns
                    FROM (
                    SELECT DISTINCT columns  
                      FROM columns        
                     WHERE conditions) AS alias000
                        GROUP BY columns ) alias000
                   ON
                    conditions
             WHERE conditions
            ) AS alias000
                 LEFT JOIN
                  (SELECT
                    columns  
                    FROM many_tables                
     WHERE many_conditions 
            ) )
        ) AS alias000
     ON condition               
       LEFT JOIN (      
    SELECT columns
    FROM            
    (SELECT
      columns
    FROM                                                   
       many_tables       
     WHERE many_conditions
            ) ) ) AS alias001  
        ,
         (SELECT
           many_columns 
         FROM                                                   
            many_tables            
           WHERE many_conditions) AS alias001
            ) AS alias001
        ON condition
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT                                     
         many_columns
       FROM many_tables               
       WHERE many_conditions
          ) AS alias001
        ON condition
        ,    
         (SELECT  DISTINCT columns
           FROM table001 alias001
           INNER JOIN                                          
                 table001 alias001              
           ON condition
            LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT columns 
            FROM (                                           
         SELECT  DISTINCT columns
          FROM tables        
          WHERE conditions
         ) AS alias001
        GROUP BY                                                  
             columns ) alias001
            ON
             condition
             WHERE                                                
                 conditions
         ) AS alias001
         LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT columns
            FROM tables            
            WHERE conditions
              ) AS alias001
            ON condition
            LEFT JOIN ( 
                 SELECT columns
             FROM
             (SELECT columns
              FROM tables               
              WHERE conditions ) AS alias001
                    ,
                    (SELECT
                        columns
                 FROM                                                   
                   tables
                 WHERE conditions ) AS alias001
                ) AS alias001
                ON condition
                 LEFT JOIN 
                                (SELECT                                     
                   columns
                 FROM                                                   
                   tables
                 WHERE conditions
                     ) AS alias001
                   ON condition
    WHERE 
    condition
    ) AS alias001
    order by column001
```

How can I make it easier for me to understand the query, so I can identify the flaws?

Comment: Start by running the sub-queries individually. Then move up as you go. Or, call your familiy first and tell them you're sorry and you won't be home for a while.

Comment: I don't know about db2, in SQL server I'd be tempted to print it all out from design view so I could get an overview of the relationships.  Might help to alias the subqueries more meaningfully first.

Comment: If any of the subqueries are identical, you should try pulling them out into CTEs (Common Table Expressions).  `SELECT DISTINCT .... JOIN` is a bit worrying, since it's probably operating over the completed set.  `DISTINCT` isn't needed if there's a `GROUP BY`.  `JOIN (SELECT ... WHERE)` should _probably_ be turned into just a regular join, although there are caveats.  1000 lines is a huge SQL statement.  You might want to turn some parts into views, or table functions, but that requires some coordination.

Comment: Almost invariably as you try to summarize that query for our consumption you will simply add confusion for example this might just be some gibberish you have accidentally introduced where the same alias is used twise on the same table and used in a join `FROM table000 alias000 INNER JOIN  table000 alias000 ON column000 = table000.column000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to simplify the query using COMMON TABLE EXPRESSIONS.

This allowed me to break the big and complex SQL query into many small and easy to understand queries.

**COMMON TABLE EXPRESSIONS:**

- Can be used to break up complex queries, especially complex joins and sub-queries
- Is a way of encapsulating a query definition.
- Persist only until the next query is run.
- Correct use can lead to improvements in both code quality/maintainability and speed.
- Can be used to reference the resulting table multiple times in the same statement (eliminate duplication in SQL).
- Can be a substitute for a view when the general use of a view is not required; that is, you do not have to store the definition in metadata.

#### Example:

```
WITH cte (Column1, Column2, Column3)
AS
(
    SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
    FROM SomeTable
)

SELECT * FROM cte
```

My new SQL looks like this:

```
------------------------------------------
--COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION 001--
------------------------------------------
WITH alias001 (column001, column002) AS (
    SELECT column005, column006
    FROM table001
    WHERE condition001
    GROUP by column008
)

--------------------------------------------
--COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION 002 --
--------------------------------------------
, alias002 (column009) as (
    select distinct column009 from table002
)

--------------------------------------------
--COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION 003 --
--------------------------------------------
, alias003 (column1, column2, column3) as (
    SELECT '1' AS column1, '1' as column2, 'name001' AS column3 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '1' AS column1, '1.1' as column2, 'name002' AS column3 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '1' AS column1, '1.2' as column2, 'name003' AS column3 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2' AS column1, '2' as column2, 'name004' AS column3 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2' AS column1, '2.1' as column2, 'name005' AS column3 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2' AS column1, '2.2' as column2, 'name006' AS column3 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '3' AS column1, '3' as column2, 'name007' AS column3 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '3' AS column1, '3.1' as column2, 'name008' AS column3 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
)
--------------------------------------------
--COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION 004 --
--------------------------------------------
, alias004 (column1) as (
    select distinct column1 from table003
)

------------------------------------------------------
--COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION 005 --
------------------------------------------------------
, alias005 (column1, column2) as (
    select column1, column2 from alias002, alias004
)

------------------------------------------------------
--COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION 006 --
------------------------------------------------------
, alias006 (column1, column2, column3, column4) as (
    SELECT column1, column2, column3, sum(column0) as column4
    FROM table004
    LEFT JOIN table005 ON column01 = column02
    group by column1, column2, column3
)

------------------------------------------------------
--COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION 007 --
------------------------------------------------------
, alias007 (column1, column2, column3, column4) as (
    SELECT column1, column2, column3, sum(column0) as column4
    FROM table006
    LEFT JOIN table007 ON column01 = column02
    group by column1, column2, column3
)

------------------------------------------------------
--COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION 008 --
------------------------------------------------------
, alias008 (column1, column2, column3, column4) as (
    select column1, column2, column3, column4 from alias007 where column5 = 123
)

----------------------------------------------------------
--COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION 009 --
----------------------------------------------------------
, alias009 (column1, column2, column3, column4) as (
    select column1, column2, 
    CASE WHEN column3 IS NOT NULL THEN column3 ELSE 0 END as column3, 
    CASE WHEN column4 IS NOT NULL THEN column4 ELSE 0 END as column4
    from table007
)

----------------------------------------------------------
--COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION 010 --
----------------------------------------------------------
, alias010 (column1, column2, column3) as (
    select column1, sum(column4), sum(column5) 
    from alias009 
    where column6 < 2005 
    group by column1
)

--------------------------------------------
--             MAIN QUERY            --
--------------------------------------------

select j.column1, n.column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, 
column3 + column5 AS column7,
column4 + column6 AS column8
from alias010 j
left join alias006 m ON (m.column1 = j.column1)
left join alias008 n ON (n.column1 = j.column1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I deal with code like this every day as we do a lot of reporting and exporting of complex data here.

**Step one is to understand the meaning of what you are doing.** If you don't understand the meaning, you can't evaluate if you got the correct results. So understand exactly what you are trying to accomplish and see if you can see the results you should see for one record in the user interface. It really helps to have something to compare to so that you can see as you go through the query how adding in new things changes the results. If your query has used single letters or something else meaningless for the derived table aliases, then as you figure out the meaning of that that derived table is supposed to be doing, then replace the alias with something more meaningful like Employees instead of A. This will make it easier for the next person who works on it to decode it later.

Then what you do is start at the innermost derived table(Or subquery if you prefer but when it is being used as a table, the term derived table is more accurate). First figure out what it is supposed to be doing. For instance maybe it is getting all the employees who have less than satisfactory performance evaluations.

Run that and check the results to see if they look correct based on the meaning of what you are doing. For instance, if you are looking at unsatisfactory evaluations and you have 10,000 employees would 5617 seem like a reasonable results set for that chunk of data? Look for repeated records. If the same person is in there three times, then likely you have problem  where you are joining one to many and getting the many back when you only want one. This can be fixed either through using aggregate functions and group by or putting another derived table in to replace the problem join.

Once you have the innermost part clear, then start checking the results of the other other derived tables, adding the code back in and checking the results until you find where either records dropped out that should not have (Hey I had 137 employees at this stage and now I only have 116. What caused that?) Remember that is only a clue to look at why that happened. There will be times as you build a complex query when the basic results will change and times when they should not have, that is why understanding the meaning of the data is critical.

Some things in general to look out for:

- How null values are handled can affect results
- Mixing implict and explict joins can cause incorrect results in some
  databases.
- At any rate you should always replace all implicit joins with
  explicit ones. That makes the code clearer and less likely to have
  errors.
- If you have implicit joins, look for accidental cross joins. They are
  very easy to introduce even in short queries, in complex ones, they
  are much more likely which is why implicit joins should never be
  used.
- If you have left joins look out for places where they get
  accidentally converted to inner joins by putting a where clause on
  the left join table (other than whether id is null). So this
  structure is a problem:

  ```
     FROM table1 t1
     LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.t1id = T2.t1id
     WHERE t2.somefield = 'test'
  ```

  and should be

  ```
     FROM table1 t1
     LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.t1id = T2.t1id
        AND t2.somefield = 'test'
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Working from the middle is commonplace in SQL and converting the set based logic of sql as sequential logic can lead to performance issues. Try hard to avoid this although I  know it will be very tempting to do so.

The first thing I would do is question the join syntax. Is this literally the way it is currently written now?

```
            select
            from tb1, tb2, tb3, tb4, tb5 ...
            left join ...
```

That from clause should look like this

```
 From tb1
 Inner join tb2 on .....
 Inner join tb3 on .....
   ....
 Left join
```

Comment: Mixing implicit and explicit joins can give strange results. And there is no instance in which a an implicit join is appropriate anymore. This stuff was replaced more than 20 years ago, get rid of them and make the code clearer, avoid accidental cross joins.

Comment: I updated the example SQL in the question with the real one SQL

Answer (score 1):

http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/data-studio

IBM provides an Eclipse-based analysis tool that has the capability of generating a Visual `EXPLAIN` graph for complex queries. It shows how indexes are used, what internal result sets are produced and combined and so on.

Example:
`SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE, DEPARTMENT WHERE WORKDEPT=DEPTNO`
[image: Visual Explain]

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I got downvoted on this answer, possibly because they thought I was proposing this as how you should build the final query. I should clarify that this is purely to try and understand what is going on. Once you understand the subqueries and how they link together, you would then use that knowledge to makes the necessary changes to the query and rebuild it in an efficient way.

I've used the technique of intermediate temp tables to troubleshoot complex queries quite a bit. They break the logic up into smaller chunks and are also useful if the original query takes a long time. You can test how to combine these intermediate tables without the overhead of rerunning the whole query. Sometimes I'll use temporary views instead of temp tables because the query optimiser can continue to use indexes on the base tables. The temporary views would get then get dropped once you've finished.

I would start from the innermost subqueries and work my way to the outside.
You're looking for subqueries which appear several times under slightly different guises, and also to give them a concise description - what are they designed to do?

Eg, replace

```
        from (
            select x1.y1, x1.y2, x1.y3 ...
            from tb1, tb2, tb3, tb4, tb5 ...
            left join ...
            where ...
            group by ...
            ) as a1
```

with

```
from daniel_view1 as a1
```

where `daniel_view1` is

```
create view daniel_view as
            select x1.y1, x1.y2, x1.y3 ...
            from tb1, tb2, tb3, tb4, tb5 ...
            left join ...
            where ...
            group by ...
```

That will already make it look cleaner. Then compare the views. Can any be merged together? You won't necessarily end up keeping the views in the final product, but they will help see the broader pattern without drowning in detail.

Alternatively, you could insert the subquery into a temp table

```
insert #daniel_work1 
select x1.y1, x1.y2, x1.y3 ...
from tb1, tb2, tb3, tb4, tb5 ...
left join ...
where ...
group by ...
```

Then replace the subquery with

```
select ... from #daniel_work1 as a1
```

The other thing you could do is to see if you can break it up into sequential steps.
If you see

```
select ... from ...
union all
select ... from ...
```

this could become

```
insert #steps
select 'step1', ...#1...
insert #steps
select 'step2', ...#2...
```

`union` is trickier because set union removes duplicate rows (rows where all of their columns are the same as another row).

By storing intermediate results in temp tables, you can look inside the query as it unfolded, and replay difficult steps. I have 'step_id' as the first column of all my debugging temp tables, so if it gets filled in stages, then you see what data applies to what stage.

There are a few tricks that give a clue about what is going on. If you see a table joined to itself like this:

```
select ... from mytable t1 inner join mytable t2 on t2.id < t.id
```

it usually means they want a cross product of the table with itself, but without duplicates. you'll get keys 1 & 2 but not 2 & 1.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a picture is worth more than a thousand words. I took your query and created a visual diagram in FlowHigh

[image]

You can interact with the diagram, e.g. expand and collapse inline views and CTEs. Let's zoom in a bit

[image]

Highlighting a component in the diagram highlights the corresponding code

[image]

You can read up in this blog post on all of the features: https://sonra.io/flowhigh/from-code-to-clarity-visualizing-sql-code-for-documentation-and-debugging/

Disclaimer: I work for the makers of FlowHigh. It is a free tool